# How do I add the value of an array to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got code which splits the key and value at the `=` sign at end `if` line, the problem is that I have lines which have more then one `=`

**For example:**

```
user = aaaa
userb = bbbb
userc = test
userd = foo = bar = test
```

I read file with *node fs* and I divide it to the key and value at the `=` so `userd` causes a problem.

I am using `var array = line.split('=');`

Then I assign it to object in the *loop*

```
myobj = {}

myobj[array[0]] = array[1];
```

This is working (my *obj* in the *loop* contains all the users) until I get to `userD`.
So how can I concatenate all the values of `userD` to **myObj**

Comment: Please, try to make it readable

Comment: The question is: what are you expecting? Is it `myobj[userd] = foobartest` or is it `myobj[userd] = foo; myobj[foo] = bar; myobj[bar] = test` or something? What do those equal signs mean here and how do you want to interpret them? Otherwise you could use `myobj[array[0]] = array.splice(1).join(' ');`

Comment: @somethinghere - I expected to be userd = foo = bar = test  like the orignal...

Comment: @AlBundy that makes no sense. What do you want to use as key and what as value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use splice function:

```
myobj[array.splice(0, 1)] = array;
```

This will cut the first item out of your array and return it as myobj parameter, the rest is going to be kept in the array, so you can either use array as an object property or let's say join it to a string:

```
myobj[array.splice(0, 1)] = array.join(", ");
```

Comment: You could have used his simple `myobj[array[0]]` in that case, this does not really improve it... The `join` I get, but add the splice to the other side so it doesn't include the key and it starts making sense... Otherwise it;s a slightly more cumbersome solution.

Comment: Thanks but in this case (in debug)I got the value = array like user=array I want it to have just the value

Comment: well, did you try the second option then?

Comment: @somethinghere omg, if you don't understand the solution or it is different from yours does not mean it is bad. This will return the requested result, so I don't see your point.

Comment: @simon OMG! If your solution runs another function to accomplish the same result as `array[0]` for which we didn't need an answer in the first place, that means it's worthy of improvement. `array.splice(0, 1) === array[0]`, which was what the OP _already had_.

Comment: Thanks can you explain what does it do (", ") this put doubule quate on the value ?and if I can avoid it?This is making an issue :)

Comment: it takes your array and merges all elements resulting with a string where the separator is `, `

Comment: @AlBundy thats nowhere in his code. He's not adding the quotes. Are you perhaps confusing it with how the console prints data or something...?

Comment: @somethinghere- Correct my mistke also 1+ to you :)

Comment: You chose your method poorly. [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) creates a new, unnecessary array, e.g.: `["userd"]`. You then rely on the implicit call to [`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/tostring) to condense that one-element array into `"userd"` for use as an object key. See [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift); it's more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

If we assume that everything *after* the first `=` sign is the value, regardless of whether theres another `=` sign then you can do this:

```
myobj[array[0]] = array.slice(1).join(' = ');
```

Now, if you want to store it simple as an array of equal values, you can do:

```
myobj[array[0]] = array.slice(1);
```

The `slice` function returns the same array starting at the element passed (it does more but thats what it's for here).

**Update** I didn't think of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32079385/2991619) answer but it's even a bit faster!

Comment: @simon Thanks for the correcting from `splice` to `slice`. It's been a long day and they are so similarly named :)

Comment: This is certainly better than the accepted `splice()` [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32077406/621962).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `Array.prototype.shift()`:

```
myobj[array.shift()] = array;
```

Unlike `Array.prototype.splice()`, `shift()` won't create an entirely new array in order to wrap up the one value we're trying to extract. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077299/how-do-i-add-the-value-of-an-array-to-an-object/32079385#comment52053649_32077406).

Here are the results from a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/splice-slice-shift); it shows operations per second (higher is better):

```
UserAgent                                       shift       slice       splice
Chrome 44.0.2403                                4,290,938   3,993,798   1,042,423
Chrome 46.0.2468                                3,631,277   4,020,712   1,098,866
Firefox 38.0                                    1,706,068   1,419,219   895,714
Firefox 40.0                                    1,739,110   1,508,623   955,794
IE 11 in Compatibility Mode 10.0.0              3,393,698   2,855,417   1,721,229
Total                                           14,761,091  13,797,769  5,714,026
```

According to these results, `shift()` is the fastest with `slice()` right behind. `splice()`, on the other hand, is a good bit slower than both... mainly because it's ill-suited to this particular task.

That said, I was surprised. I expected [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32077514/621962) to be the fastest.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the testing, I didn't expect this either. Firefox looks slow, though... Didn't expect that to be so dramatically different either.

Comment: Thanks Canon but when I use myobj[array.shift()] = array; I got the value as array and I need is as "string" like...

Comment: @AlBundy then use [`array.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) or [`array.join()`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mdn%20array.prototype.join) with whichever delimiter you'd prefer.